# Want to run migrations from one Vagrant VM to another using php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel, migration, vagrant, artisan-migrate

I have two VMs in vagrant.

My app is on the [web] VM (192.168.10.10). 
My db is on the [db] VM (192.168.10.11).

I deployed my app to the [web] VM and then from within the [web] VM, I want to run my migrations so it migrates to the [db] VM.

Essentially, I want to migrate from one VM to another (192.168.10.10 > 192.168.10.11)

I changed my database.php file so it has the right IP and I triple checked my [db] VM to make sure that the credentials match:

```
return array(
    'connections' => array(

        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '192.168.10.11',
            'database'  => 'demo',
            'username'  => 'demo',
            'password'  => 'demo',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'auth' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '192.168.10.11',
            'database'  => 'demo',
            'username'  => 'demo',
            'password'  => 'demo',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    ),
);
```

When I run "php artisan migrate" from my [web] VM it errors out:

```
[PDOException]                             
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  

migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--force] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [--pretend] [--seed]
```

Any idea what is happening to refuse the connection?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using a multi machine Vagrantfile ? can you ping 192.168.10.11 from 192.168.10.10 ? if so you need to check `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`and comment the `bind-address`
 line or assign the value `0.0.0.0`

Comment: It is a multi-machine vagrantfile, and I can ping 192.168.10.11 from 192.168.10.10. I tried your fix and it didn't work. I'm getting a Connection Timed Out error (even without your fix)